# Changing package name of App-Engine side of App-Engine Connected Android Project not reflected on Android Side

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working on an Appengine Connected Android Project. I am using Google Eclipse Plugin. Anyway, after finishing my project and having it working for a few days, I decided to change the package names of the server code. But then when I generate the Cloud Endpoint Client Library, the new package name is not reflected on the client. I still see the old name there: e.g. in `endpoints-libs/…`. Does anyone know how I might fix this?

But something else also happens that is very interesting. The app works fine with the new server. When I run the android app and look at the log, it is calling the new server by the appropriate new name. So clearly the mapping between App Engine and Android is correct. So why is the name not updating in the client? image my old package name was `com.globs.game` and the new name is now `com.pans.game`, if ever that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It turns out I forgot to change my class's attributes:

```
@Api(name = "myappapi”,
  namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "mycompany.com", ownerName = "mycompany.com", packagePath = ""),
  version = "1",
  description = "myapp API",
  defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```